# Ruby on Mac OSX Sierra via Mac Ports

Tags: ruby, macos, macports

I'm on macOS Sierra. I installed ruby 2.5 via macports (/opt/local/bin/ruby2.5). However, I also have ruby 2.0 sitting in /usr/bin/ruby -- not sure where that comes from -- its not a macports package. How can I get my system to use the newer ruby 2.5 system wide? 
When I try to remove/rename /usr/bin/ruby I get "Operation not permitted" even as super user.

Comment: Ruby comes bundled with osx. Have you tried using `RVM`?

Comment: You do NOT want to change the default ruby.  use `rvm` or `rbenv` (I prefer the latter) to manage the version you use for project work

Comment: Personally I prefer asdf.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin` is Apple-land. You should not change it, and Apple has implemented a feature called "System Integrity Protection" (SIP) that actively prevents modification of files with this protection enabled, one of which is `/usr/bin/ruby`. There are ways to disable SIP, but there are better alternatives to change the default ruby.

Instead, the general method to prefer specific versions of self-installed tools is to set `$PATH` so that a folder under your control comes before `/usr/bin`. MacPorts already does this by prepending `/opt/local/bin`. However, MacPorts does not, by default, create a `/opt/local/bin/ruby -> ruby2.5` symlink, because you might have multiple versions of Ruby installed and it would not know which one you want to make the default.

For this reason, MacPorts comes with a mechanism called `port select` (see `port help select`) that allows you to manage a `/opt/local/bin/ruby` symlink. In your case, `port select --list ruby` should show a list of choices, and `sudo port select --set ruby ruby25` should make ruby2.5 the default. Note that Shells usually cache the lookup from a command name to the path that provides it, so this will only be effective after opening a new shell, or running `hash -r` in the current one.

In the specific case of Ruby, there are also tools available to manage different versions of Ruby side-by-side, such as rbenv and rvm.